# File upload Javascript Extension managing

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I have the code below which checks the extension suitability to file upload. It is switched to .xxx  file type. When I upload JPEG it doesn't work can you please help me.

```
var uploadedFileType = $("#glrImageFile").val().substring($("#glrImageFile").val().length - 3);
if (uploadedFileType != "" && uploadedFileType != "jpg" && uploadedFileType != "jpg" && uploadedFileType != "bmp" && uploadedFileType != "gif" && uploadedFileType != "png") {
   alert("Only jpg, png, gif, bmp image types are supported");
   processing = false;
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm getting this well, you are trying to limit the file extensions for a file upload tag to "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp". I can see you have repeated "jpg" check twice in your code, so I assume you meant "jpeg" instead of "jpg" (have you?).
So you code might look like this (with a little enhancement in getting file extension):

```
var uploadedFileType = $("#glrImageFile").val().split('.').pop();
if (uploadedFileType != "" && uploadedFileType != "jpg" && uploadedFileType != "jpg" && uploadedFileType != "bmp" && uploadedFileType != "gif" && uploadedFileType != "png") {
    alert("Only jpg, png, gif, bmp image types are supported");
    processing = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention . i re writed the code in the purpose of detecting '.' instead of  detecting last 3 digits    var uploadedFileType = $("#glrImageFile").val();
             var ext = uploadedFileType.substring(uploadedFileType.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

             if (ext != "gif" && ext != "jpeg" && ext != "jpg" && ext != "bmp") {
                 alert("Only jpg, png, gif, bmp image types are supported");
                 processing = false;
                 return false;
             }